# Detect python dependencies with yocto with setuptools

Tags: python, dependencies, yocto

Adding custom python packages in my OS, my team sometimes have the issue of packages missing, detected at runtime.

Those dependencies, are run dependencies set in the recipe which one can miss easily.

Is there a way with setuptools to add a step to check the requires.txt or setup.py generated during `do_configure` and in this case throw an error message. I couldn't find any mechanism in `setuptools` but I maybe miss something

I am using yocto morty. Thanks

Comment: `devtool add` can generate a skeleton recipe and it will scan for such dependencies automatically. Maybe you can adopt their scanner and make a class that automatically checks recipes?